# Update computed column in entity framework 6

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

how to update value of computed column in EF6 I am using this :

```
 HR_LEAVE_TBL hrLeaveTbl = context.HR_LEAVE_TBL.First(x => x.HASH == id);
                    hrLeaveTbl.APPROVED_BY_MANAGER = 1;
                    context.SaveChanges();
```

but doesn't work
but the value will not changed but when I change `StoreGeneratedPattern` to `None` the update work against the database I am using `Asp.net MVC with SQL Server 2012 standard edition`

Comment: A computed column cannot be updated: its value is calculated!! How could you set a calculated value? This makes non sense at all.

Comment: the field is default in the databse

Comment: Then that's definitely not a computed column. Change your question title and content to reflect that what you want to do is to get a default DB value. That's a different animal... You must rewrite all the question and explain the real problem. BTW, if it's a default it has nothing to do with the update but with the insert. You should get a clear idea of what you want to do before asking for help.

Answer (score 0):

**It's Computed so it's not update-able.**

You can't update the computed column you may update the values that this column depends on.